# Animating a Cell Fracture Explosion

Tags: keyframes

I am doing a Minecraft animation, and I am going to use cell fracture for an explosion. I had a character throw some TNT, I created the cell fracture on an alternate mesh, and I swapped the whole and cell fractured as it explodes. I animated the *Rigid Body Physics* before the explosion, and I turned it off after. I did the margin thing, but it doesn't move at all. It's active, and it won't respond to keyframes (normal). I set it to a location on frame 33 and to another on frame 34. When I go back to frame 33, it's still at location the frame 34 location. Essentially, it only responds during the whole thing to the most recent location keyframe. I did set the physics to all the pieces. Please help.

Before (both object and fractured are there)

[image]

After (May look like something's happening, but it just stops). Before that, it looks like that TNT is just chilling there and not responding to keyframes.

[image]